# BigQuery data not matching Firebase Analytics

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm currently trying to query BigQuery to grab the analytics data that Firebase is exporting to it. I'm able to successfully query the tables and get data back but when I run my query, the returned number does not match what Firebase is giving me for that particular day.

Right now I'm just trying to grab all first_open events for a single day, I hope to make this so I can tally up the month and week also.

```
SELECT count(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros))) as dateAccessed 
FROM `table_here` 
WHERE FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros)) = '01/05/2017'
```

The above query returns `88` where in my firebase console, the `first_open` event only has a count of `14`. I'm not familiar with how the app that sends the events works.

Running the query on the `intraday` table gives me `11` events, where in Firebase it's only reading a single event being tracked today.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data was not matching due to the comparison of the wrong fields. In order to get the correct data I had to run a query on the table to `UNNEST` `event_dim` then compare the count of those rows to the events section within firebase.